# Why is this derivative correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why is the following correct? Can't understand it.

$$\dfrac{d}{dz}\bigg(\dfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^{z}+e^{-z}}\bigg)=1-\dfrac{(e^z-e^{-z})^2}{(e^{z}+e^{-z})^2}$$

Comment: Do you know the rule for taking the derivative of a quotient?

Comment: Note the derivative of the bottom is the top and vice versa. By the quotient rule, the derivative of the entire expression is ${B^2-T^2\over B^2}=1-{T^2\over B^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the quotient rule for taking derivatives:

$$\dfrac{d}{dz}\bigg(\dfrac{\overbrace{e^z-e^{-z}}^{\large f(x)}}{\underbrace{e^{z}+e^{-z}}_{\large g(x)}}\bigg)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

In this case, $\;f'(x) = e^z + e^{-z} = g(x),\;$ and $\;g'(x) = e^z - e^{-z} = f(x),\;$  so we get that the derivative  $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) = \frac{g^2 (x) - f^2(x)}{g^2(x)} = 1 - \dfrac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)} = 1-\dfrac{(e^z-e^{-z})^2}{(e^{z}+e^{-z})^2}$$

Comment: Very nice use of brackets - I need to use those features more! +1

Comment: Love that braces. ;-)

Comment: @Babak: I can only hope to be as good a teacher as you clearly are!

Answer (score 1):

As $$\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}=\frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}=1-\frac2{e^{2z}+1}$$

$$\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}\right)$$

$$=-2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac1{e^{2z}+1}\right)$$

$$=-2\frac{2e^{2z}}{-(e^{2z}+1)^2}=\frac{4e^{2z}}{(e^{2z}+1)^2}$$

$$=\frac{(e^{2z}+1)^2-(e^{2z}-1)^2}{(e^{2z}+1)^2}\text{ using } 4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$

$$=1-(\frac{e^{2z}-1)^2}{(e^{2z}+1)^2}=1-\dfrac{(e^z-e^{-z})^2}{(e^{z}+e^{-z})^2}$$ dividing the numerator & the denominator by $e^{2z}\ne0$